# How do I turn this array into one array in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, javascript-debugging

ExampleArray = [["Relationship", "Subscriber"],
["memberId", "12345"],
["MemberName", "Test Member"]]

How would I turn the above into just one array with all those key value pairs like this below:

newExampleArray = ["Relationship": "Subscriber", "memberId": "12345","MemberName": "Test Member"]

Comment: P.S. This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). To get better help, ask about the "X" problem instead of the "Y" problem.

Answer (score 4):

`["Relationship": "Subscriber", "memberId": "12345","MemberName": "Test Member"]` is not a valid array. Arrays are indexed values, such as:

```
["Relationship", "Subscriber", "memberId", "12345","MemberName", "Test Member"]
```

While an Object would be:

```
{"Relationship": "Subscriber", "memberId": "12345","MemberName": "Test Member"}
```

To get the first form, use:

```
newExampleArray = exampleArray.flat();
```

To get the second form, use:

```
newExampleObject = Object.fromEntries(exampleArray);
```